# Deploying Grails war on Jetty gives ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: grails, deployment, jetty, war, ibm-midrange

I've tried deploying my grails app with tomcat on a linux pc and everything works fine.  If I try deploying the same app with jetty on an IBM AS400 I get an incredibly long stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing  bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)   
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)   
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:63) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:260) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)          
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)

...

Caused by:                                                    
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.class$(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.$get$$class$org$apache$commons$dbcp$BasicDataSource(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:151)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1073)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin.invokeMethod(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1_closure8.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3649)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1408)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$171.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:736)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:569)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:511)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:528)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:156)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
Caused by:
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:59)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:407)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.<clinit>(BasicDataSource.java:57)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.class$(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.$get$$class$org$apache$commons$dbcp$BasicDataSource(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:151)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1073)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin.invokeMethod(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1_closure8.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3649)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1408)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$171.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.datasource.DataSourceGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:736)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:569)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:511)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:528)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:156)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:733)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
```

Searching the internet hasn't turned up anything useful.  Any help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using Grails version 2.0.3 and Jetty version 7.6.3.

Here is my datasource config for the grails app:

```
dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        pooled = true
        url = "jdbc:as400://localhost;naming=system;libraries=*LIBL;errors=full"
        driverClassName = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
        username = "user"
        password = "pass"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect.class
}
```

It may help to note that I am using the [systemitools plugin](http://code.google.com/p/grails400utils/) for Grails.

**UPDATE:** I removed all other webapps so that mine would be the only webapp run when jetty starts and it worked fine.  The problem seems to be when a different webapp starts before the grails app.

Comment: not sure your meant to all them AS400s any more (not for about 10 years). still can you post your datasource config (minus the obvious private details)

Comment: @Gareth The 400 is not my medium of choice, but I don't get paid to make those choices.  I'll have to remove a chunk of the stacktrace to post my config or I won't have room.

Comment: don't get me wrong ... there isn't anything wrong with using an AS400 (iSeries, System/i or what ever IBM are calling it this year :)

Comment: Is the jdbc driver in the war file or is it part of the JDK?

Comment: @Gareth The driver is in the war file.  They prefer not to call it an AS400 anymore because it makes it sound old... yeah.  I believe they want it to be called iSeries/PowerSeries now.

Comment: try pulling that driver out of the war and putting it in the lib directory of jetty (or where ever jetty has it's jars)

Comment: @Gareth I've tried both putting it in the jetty/lib/ and in the webapp's own lib dir jetty/webapps/myapp/lib/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24000/discussion-between-gareth-davis-and-weezle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around at least.  If I change my database driver in my datasource to use db2 instead of as400 (and change the url accordingly) then everything is fine.  I had tried converting the webapps to Grails hoping that it would solve the problem, but it didn't.  Not until I switched to using the db2 driver instead of the as400 driver.

```
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
```

Multiple apps using the db2 driver is fine.  Some apps using db2 and one using as400 is fine.  Multiple apps using the as400 driver is not fine.

I'm still not sure exactly why that is.  If someone has an idea then please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have Spring create the Data Source.
That's against the rules with the Servlet Spec.

Have Spring just reference the JNDI DataSource that you have defined in the webapp container.

1) The real server side / container `DataSource`

Setup the server side JNDI reference to the real `javax.sql.DataSource`, call it anything you want (in this example, we'll call it `jdbc/myContainerDS`)

Use the documentation at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource

2) The WEB-INF/web.xml resource-ref

You *must* setup the `<resource-ref>` reference in `web.xml` (this is a required part of the servlet spec that some webapp containers fail to follow).  Again, use the documentation above for help.

3) The Spring bean reference to the JNDI provided DataSource

Setup the Spring side bean to reference the JNDI datasource on the server side.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myContainerDS"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please see my update.  It appears as if my issue may have been caused by having two grails apps starting at the same time in Jetty.  Do you think your solution would resolve this?

Comment: Having the server initialize the JNDI at the server level will likely solve the problem.

Comment: I got my webapp working on its own using the JNDI DataSource, but when I add the other apps back to jetty I get the same error as before.

Comment: I suspect you might get some milage moving the JDBC driver up to the app server lib directory, rather than having both apps with a copy, the issue does like something breaking in the driver registation. I really won't worry too much about having a Datasource defined in the app